# How do for loops work in Python? Like deep down what process in happening?

Tags: python, for-loop

I am learning Python and having a lot of trouble with for loops. I know they are similar to while loops. My basic understanding is that they go through a list item by item and apply a block to it.

But I cannot seem to write a functioning for loop, I just can't wrap my head around something. Also when I look at example ones in my classes (Udacity) I don't understand how that works.

Here is an example of code that works, but I couldn't come up with that code or figure out why it is working:

```
def measure_udacity(U):
    count = 0
    for e in U:
        if e[0] == 'U':
            count = count + 1
    return count

print measure_udacity(['Dave','Sebastian','Katy'])
print measure_udacity(['Umika','Umberto'])
print measure_udacity(['udacity', 'United States', 'umbrella', 'U2'])
```

The three prints output 0, 2 and 2. I guess what I don't understand is how does this line work?

```
        if e[0] == 'U':
```

If you are specifying [0], how does it then get applied to 'Sebastian' and 'Katy'? which are in positions [1] and [2]?

I was trying to write the same for loop before I saw the solution and had something more like this:

```
def measure_udacity(ulist):
    i = 0
    j = 0
    for i in ulist:
        if ulist[j] == 'U':
            i += 1
            j += 1
        else:
            j+=1
        return i
```

Basically trying to advance the position of where it was searching in the list for 'U'. This worked out about as well as a sack of bricks trying to float. So far Python has been very simple and the fact that I'm having so much trouble on for loops is telling me there is some basic thing about them I don't understand.

Comment: `e` is a string, `e[0]` is its first character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the function `measure_udacity` is called, the variable `U` is a list of strings.  The first time it's called, `U` has three elements and they are 'Dave', 'Sebastian' and 'Katy'.  The `for` statement causes the indented block to run exactly once for each element, and the elements are assigned in turn to the variable `e`.  The first time through the loop `e='Dave'`, the second time through the loop `e='Sebastian'` and the third time `e='Katy'`.  Python causes these assignments to the variable `e` to happen automatically; you don't need to write any extra code to do that (as you were trying to do in your question).  That is the answer to your question about how to access all three strings in the list - it happens automatically because the computer goes through the loop three times, and each time `e` has a different value.

You asked about the line `if e[0] == 'U'`.  I hope you can see now that `e` is a string, one of the strings from the list `U`.  `e[0]` is simply the first character in the string, so this line compares the first character to 'U'.  If it's true the counter increments by one.  By the time you've looped through the entire list, the counter will equal the number of words that started with U.

I hope that helps, good luck learning.

Answer (score 2):

In Python, `for` loops are essentially [`foreach` loops](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreach_loop), where the iterating variable is a loop item, rather than an index.

If you want to get the index as well, you can call `enumerate` on your list:

```
for index, item in enumerate(items):
    print "{item} is at index {index}".format(item=item, index=index)
```

> The three prints output 0, 2 and 2. I guess what I don't understand is how does this line work?

```
    if e[0] == 'U':
```

> If you are specifying [0], how does it then get applied to 'Sebastian' and 'Katy'? which are in positions [1] and [2]?

In this case, `e` is not the top-level `U` list, but an item of `U`. `e[0]` is then the first character of the string `e`, not the first item of the list `U`.